# Who is the reigning queen?

Tags: story

A boy and a girl (Jack and Jill) were playing chess. The girl played with Red pieces and the boy played with White pieces, untraditional colors but all traditional rules.

Near the end of the game, it was almost a stalemate, and the Red pieces had a rook on the enemy side and no other remaining pieces besides the King.

But the White had no other pieces besides their King and a pawn which reached the other side.

Suddenly, a cat jumped onto the table which caused a pail of water to flip onto board, scattering the pieces everywhere, and both Jack and Jill went tumbling over. Fortunately, they still remembered their pieces.

Who is the reigning queen?

Comment: What do you mean by reigning queen? And just to clarify, is red's rook threatening white's pawn? And also, shouldn't white's pawn be a queen since it is on the other side

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance Regarding red's rook, if you noticed, the rook is on the enemy's side (white's home base). However, the white pawn is on the home base of the red, and since they reached the other side, the rook could not have threatened across the map otherwise they would have taken it. Regarding your second comment, it seems you accidentally solved it unawares; it seems that you tipped off Krad Cigol to the solution, unrealizing that you in fact solved it (since you posted 18 hours ago and his answer was 7 hours ago). (Or, maybe he figured it out himself and didn't see your comment).

Comment: I thought that that answer would be too simple, and decided not to post it.

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance *Misdirection, misdirection indeed*

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance I didn’t see your comment, but now I see you got it before me. Nice one! +1

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance feel free to post your answer as well. You did guess it before me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reigning queen is

> White

This is because

> When a pawn reaches the other end, it can be promoted to a queen. Red does not have a pawn or a queen.

Answer (score 6):

This is all related to

> Alice through the looking glass https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Through_the_Looking-Glass

We have the unusual chess colors:

> Red and white pieces (Red queen, White queen)

and a cat

> Alice is playing with a white kitten (whom she calls "Snowdrop") and a black kitten (whom she calls "Kitty")

But as to who the reigning queen is, I am not sure, as there are at least three canditates, but I am  guessing

> Alice (Chapter nine is called Queen Alice):

Comment: Upvote for your creativity! That does seem to be one possible answer.